# SQL Passing Table Date for Date

Tags: db2

Wondering how I can pass the RECEIVEDDATETIME to the statement below. What am I missing in my SQL statement?

I added an inner join to my CALENDAR table and TESTDATA table to pass the T.RECEIVEDDATETIME as the date from the original example thanks to Mark Barinstein.

This statement gets the C.WORKDATE from my tblCalendar, but I need to have the T.RECEIVEDDATETIME to pass to get my desired "DUEDATE".

I created a "tblCalendar" because I read that it was easier to reference a Calendar for true workdays...to exclude weekends and holidays and to account for leap years. Unsure if this is the best practice, but seemed straight forward to not code for exceptions. So I created the tblCalendar that includes ALL DATEs from 2017 until 2050 and holidays. The data below only represents partially January 2019 as I haven't found a way to attach a table here:

```
tblCalendar (partial)
DATE        NUMDAYOFWK       DAYOFWK      HOLIDAY
01/01/2019    3              Tuesday      YES
01/02/2019    4              Wednesday  
01/03/2019    5              Thursday   
01/04/2019    6              Friday 
01/05/2019    7              Saturday   
01/06/2019    1              Sunday 
01/07/2019    2              Monday 
01/08/2019    3              Tuesday    
01/09/2019    4              Wednesday  
01/10/2019    5              Thursday   
01/11/2019    6              Friday 
01/12/2019    7              Saturday   
01/13/2019    1              Sunday 
01/14/2019    2              Monday 
01/15/2019    3              Tuesday    
01/16/2019    4              Wednesday  
01/17/2019    5              Thursday   
01/18/2019    6                  Friday 
01/19/2019    7              Saturday   
01/20/2019    1              Sunday 
01/21/2019    2              Monday       YES
```

The tblTestData table holds the core data where I reference all fields needed for my reports.

```
tblTestData Columns (partial) - DeliveryDays would reference the 2nd parameter BusDayAdd that was noted in the previous SQL.

ID                  RECEIVEDDATE       DeliveryDays     Address
T-20190116-255      01/16/2019          2             1234 Address
T-20190117-255      01/17/2019          2             3657 Address
T-20190118-222      01/18/2019          2             9999 Address
T-20190119-255      01/19/2019          2
T-20190120-255      01/20/2019
T-20190121-255      01/21/2019
T-20190303-1        03/03/2019
```

The Desired end results would look like the following taking into account the RECEIVEDDATETIME in my tblTestData and reference the tblCalendar table to exclude weekends and holidays to give the correct due date.

```
ID              RECEIVEDDATE            DeliveryDays    DueDate    Address
T-20190116-255  1/16/2019                2             1/18/2019     1234 Address
T-20190117-255  1/17/2019   2   1/22/2019   3657 Address
T-20190118-222  1/18/2019   2   1/23/2019   9999 Address
T-20190119-255  1/19/2019   2   1/23/2019   10000 Address
T-20190120-255  1/20/2019   2   1/23/2019   10001 Address
T-20190121-255  1/21/2019   2   1/23/2019   10002 Address
T-20190121-256  1/22/2019   2   1/24/2019   10003 Address
T-20190303-1    3/3/2019    3   3/6/2019    10004 Address
T-20190121-257  3/15/2019   7   3/26/2019   10005 Address
```

I have tried various statements by rewriting the code to wrap the SQL string to pass the table "RECEIVEDDATETIME", but each time the "DUEDATE" comes back {NULL}.

```
SELECT T.ID, VARCHAR_format(T.RECEIVEDDATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') RECDATE, 

(select VARCHAR_FORMAT(WORKDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') DUEDATE 

from 

(Select
WORKDATE, T.RECEIVEDDATETIME,
sum(case when C.HOLIDAY='YES' or C.NUMDAYOFWK in (7,1) then 0 else 1 end) over  (order by C.WORKDATE) BUSDAYADD

from tblCALENDAR C

--ADDED INNER JOIN TO GET T.RECEIVEDDATETIME TO FEED AUTOMATICALLY FROM TESTDATA TABLE

INNER JOIN TESTDATA T
      ON 
VARCHAR_FORMAT(C.WORKDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = VARCHAR_FORMAT(T.RECEIVEDDATETIME,'MM/DD/YYYY')

where C.WORKDATE > VARCHAR_FORMAT(T.RECEIVEDDATETIME,'MM/DD/YYYY')) -- 1-st PARAMETER TO CAPTURE RECEIVEDDATETIME 

WHERE BUSDAYADD = ? -- 2-nd parameter to add the number of days needed to be added to RECEIVEDDATETIME 

order by WORKDATE --3rd Parameter
fetch first 1 row only) 

FROM TESTDATA T
WHERE ID = 'T-20190303-1'
```

When I run the SQL, I get {NULL} for my results for DUEDATE:

```
ID              RECDATE     DUEDATE
T-20190303-1    03/03/2019  {NULL}
```

The results should be:

```
 ID             RECDATE     DUEDATE
 T-20190303-1   03/03/2019  03/05/2019
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should provide your test data in both tables (with column types as well) and the result needed. Please, rewrite your question with this additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided inconsistent data in both tables: your calendar ends too early for all records in the `tblTestData` table except the 1-st one.
Let me provide absolutely the same query, which I already sent earlier to your another question.

```
with tblCalendar (DATE, HOLIDAY) as (values
  (date(to_date('01/16/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/17/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/18/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/19/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/20/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/21/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 'YES')

, (date(to_date('01/22/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/23/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/24/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/25/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/26/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/27/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/28/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/29/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/30/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('01/31/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('02/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('02/02/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('02/03/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('02/04/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')
, (date(to_date('02/05/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), '')

)
, tblTestData (ID, RECEIVEDDATE, DeliveryDays) as (values
  ('T-20190116-255', date(to_date('01/16/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190117-255', date(to_date('01/17/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190118-222', date(to_date('01/18/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190119-255', date(to_date('01/19/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190120-255', date(to_date('01/20/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190121-255', date(to_date('01/21/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190121-256', date(to_date('01/22/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 2)
, ('T-20190303-1'  , date(to_date('01/23/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 3)
, ('T-20190121-257', date(to_date('01/24/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), 7)
)
select m.*, t.date as DUEDATE
--, dayofweek(date) as DAYOFWK, dayname(date) as DAY
from tblTestData m
, table
(
  select date
  from table 
  (
    select 
      date
    , sum(case when HOLIDAY='YES' or dayofweek(date) in (7,1) then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as dn_
    from tblCalendar t
    where t.date > m.RECEIVEDDATE
  )
  where dn_ = m.DeliveryDays
  fetch first 1 row only
) t;
```

The result is:

```
ID              RECEIVEDDATE DAYS   DUEDATE
--------------  ------------ ----   ----------
T-20190116-255    2019-01-16    2   2019-01-18
T-20190117-255    2019-01-17    2   2019-01-22
T-20190118-222    2019-01-18    2   2019-01-23
T-20190119-255    2019-01-19    2   2019-01-23
T-20190120-255    2019-01-20    2   2019-01-23
T-20190121-255    2019-01-21    2   2019-01-23
T-20190121-256    2019-01-22    2   2019-01-24
T-20190303-1      2019-01-23    3   2019-01-28
T-20190121-257    2019-01-24    7   2019-02-04
```

Comment: Thank you; this is working now after seeing your example with my test data. Apologies for the inconsistency of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT of the DUEDATE is

```
INNER JOIN TESTDATA T
   ON VARCHAR_FORMAT(C.WORKDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = VARCHAR_FORMAT(T.RECEIVEDDATETIME,'MM/DD/YYYY')
where C.WORKDATE > VARCHAR_FORMAT(T.RECEIVEDDATETIME,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

This means you join on the Equality and then restrict to Workdate > Receiveddatetime 
that might be the problem...